# Reading sql query result in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Am very new to c# sorry if it is lame question, am trying to allow the user to do some operation based on result of my sql query. Here is what I tried

```
SqlConnection oConn = new SqlConnection();
oConn.ConnectionString = "My connection string");
oConn.Open();
SqlCommand oCmd = oConn.CreateCommand();
oCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
oCmd.CommandText = "if exists (select 1 from accesstab where LoginName = @CurrentUser and AccessList = 'Admin') select 1 else select 0";
oCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CurrentUser", currentUser);
SqlDataAdapter ada = new SqlDataAdapter(oCmd);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ada.Fill(ds);
string accessflag = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
if (accessflag == "1") {
    //my business logic
}
else {
    lblResult.Text = "You don't have access;
}
```

It works as expected, but is this right way to do this ? or this can be done in any better way ?

Edit : The reason why I did not post this in codereview site is, I felt this is very basic question and not fit for codereview site.

Comment: "It works as expected" - then this question is not for SO. Have you tried asking on codereview?

Comment: if it is working code, it should go to codereview SO. classes like `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` deal with unmanaged resources, implement `IDisposing` and should therefore be wrapped in `using`.  The else branch would not compile due to unterminated string literal. For variable declaration we nowadays use the `var` keyword instead of repeating the class name.

Comment: Quite ok, but put your SQL query logic in a separate class and add some methods (for example: ExecuteQuery) to prevent duplicate code. Pass you query and a list of SqlParameters and return a DataSet/DataTable/etc...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It belongs on Code Review.

Comment: This is a very primitive way to query an sql database. Your options are [entity framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee712907(v=vs.113).aspx) or Ado.NET which is lower level (and more complex).

Comment: Just to answer to your edit : CodeReview **is for very basic reviews too**

Comment: @VDWWD - This isn't offtopic, you should have voted to move to Codereview site!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this example, your query only returns one field, so it would be simpler and cleaner to use:

```
command.ExecuteScalar()
```

rather than creating a `DataSet`.

Also you should be sure to dispose unmanaged resources; typically this is done with the `using`statement:

```
using(var oConn = new SqlConnection())
{
    oConn.Open();
    using (var oCmd = oConn.CreateCommand())
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Finally, it would be cleaner to separate presentation, business and data access logic into separate classes.

Comment: Ah finally some meaningful answer. Thanks will look into `ExecuteScalar` .. cheers